# Canny means shrewd or wise how does uncanny turn out to be mysterious?

Tags: etymology, differences

*Canny* means 'shrewd' while *uncanny* means mysterious. How?

Comment: Welcome to [ELU.SE] @ezio. 
Sharing your research helps everybody - show what you've found already, and explain what it is you don't understand.

Comment: Have you looked at the etymology section of dictionary definitions? Or if not, have you looked at websites like http://etymonline.com? Check there and see if that explains things to you. If not, come back and tell us what you've found and what's still puzzling you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Uncanny* is indeed derived directly from *canny* and carries down the same root sense.

*canny* originates from *can/ ken* meaning to know (the how or why of) something, so that its usage applies to someone/ something with the knowledge/ knack about something -- shrewd in a way as the OP notes in the question.

*uncanny* is counter-intuitive/ unnatural or fails to make sense in a rational/logical way. "From *un*- +‎ *canny*; thus “beyond one's ken,” or outside one's familiar knowledge or perceptions." ([Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/uncanny))

See the etymologies of *[canny](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=canny)* and *[uncanny](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=uncanny)* (also, *[can](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=can&allowed_in_frame=0)*) on etymonline.

Answer (score 1):

The origin of *uncanny* is, [*un* "not" + *cann* "know"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/uncanny) from Middle English *can* "to know" (1st/3rd person singuler of the ME verb *cunnen* "to know"), originally from [Old English *can* 3rd per. singular of *cunnan*](http://www.verbix.com/webverbix/go.php?D1=23&T1=cunnan), thus mysterious in the sense that something is unknown.  [*Canny* means today (and in Middle English) "knowing"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/canny) and hence shrewd.  Wiktionary points out, as you do: "Note: In common modern usage, 'canny' and 'uncanny' are no longer antonyms."